# Using an Indirect Citation

Tags: citations

I am writing a research paper. There are a few known results for which I want to add citation in my paper. However, all those results have already been cited in a well-reputed book.

Can I cite the book directly? For example: Result 1 [book citation], Result 2 [book citation],...,etc.

or should I add the proper citation of each of the results? like this: Result 1 [this journal], Result 2 [that journal],...,etc.

Note that the results in the book are not explicitly explained in any section. They are just briefly stated in the chapter notes. And, if I cite the book directly, I am feeling like I am not adding to the citation count of the original authors who deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that you have used all the sources, you must cite them all.